# Не работает VideoView

Tags: android, java

```
 videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/video/1/4.mp4"));
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus(0);
    videoView.start(); // начинаем воспроизведение автоматически
```

Получаю ошибку, не удалось воспроизвести.
Файл есть!

Answer (score 1):

Android поддерживает не все возможные видео кодеки (как не странно). В [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) есть список поддеживаемых кодеков в зависимости от версии Android.

Comment: @metalurgus, H.264 AVC все поддерживает, что не так? У меня устройство Lenovo A316i andro 4.2. В чем же подвох-то?

Comment: @metalurgus есть видео, которое весит 30 метров, оно в формате mp4, я использую farmFactory, в какой формат конвертить и в каком разрешении, чтобы на всех устройствах запустилось норм, разер был маленьким и разрешение запустилось на устройтсва 480*800 - 2000*1000?

Comment: @metalurgus, это дело не в Viedo View

Вот ошибка смотри

02-13 14:33:51.058  29143-29143/com.example.myapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource: IOException! uri=android.resource://com.example.myapp/raw/ddd.3gp
02-13 14:33:51.069  29143-29156/com.example.myapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
02-13 14:33:51.121  29143-29143/com.example.myapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)

3GP то везде восрпоизводит. Самое главное, что  если я 3GP или MP4 на телефоне запущу через левый проиывагрвтель, то все ок, а через андроид не хочет. Что делать?